# Celleditor setting value is not fine in Firefox

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I'am designing an application in Extjs4.2 where one grid is there with cellediting plugin. My requirement is on cell click combobox should be displayed. When no data there for combobox in chrome its fine but in FF the element is displaying.

For a better clarity am attaching the screenshot below

[image]
Any help is highly appreciated

Thanks in Advance

Comment: can u put it in a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

This might happen, when you didn't specify this columns's dataIndex field in model. Also you need to initialize that field with some value, at least empty string.